# ubuntu hadoop class path

Tags: java, hadoop

This is the tutorial that I am following:

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Running_Hadoop_On_Ubuntu_Linux_(Single-Node_Cluster)

I am trying to format the hdfs namenode

```
root@alexander-desktop:/usr/local/hadoop/bin# ./hadoop namenode -format
    ./hadoop: line 258: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java: No such file or directory
    ./hadoop: line 289: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java: No such file or directory
    ./hadoop: line 289: exec: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

I have also included the changes i made to the /`etc/bash.bashrc`. These were made to configure the path:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
export JDK_HOME=$JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

I checked to see if the java variable was being set
`echo $JAVA_HOME`. Below is the path

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
```

`which java` returns a different binary than `$JAVA_HOME` points to. What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: It's obviously thinking `java` is somewhere else. Rather than changing the system-wide `.bashrc` (is your filename a typo?) change your own. From the shell prompt type `which java` to see what it's trying to execute. Take it from there.

Comment: ok i checked which java returns /usr/bin/java I did gather it was in the wrong place but was not sure how to fix it

Comment: Well, that might be a symlink to the real Java--put *your* Java path *first* so it overrides what's in the existing `$PATH`. Since you put yours second it'll find all the default javas first.

Comment: How do i put my java files first so that it overrides whats in the existing $PATH

Comment: `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`

Comment: for some reason i went to run the command again and it stopped working it says the $JAVA_HOME is not set.

Comment: i fixed the problem I experimented with environmental and entered some environmental variables. So i could set the variables throughout the system and not just in a certain place. The problem. I was having was I had not set the hadoop-env.sh

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java
export HADOOP_HOME=/path/to/hadoop
```

Step 2 : Set JAVA_HOME path to conf/hadoop-env.sh

Step 3 : conf/core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Step 4 : conf/hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Step 5 : conf/mapred-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:9001</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Step 6 : Login SSH localhost and Format a new distributed-filesystem

```
bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

Step 7 : Start the hadoop daemons:

```
bin/start-all.sh
```

Step 8 : Check the NameNode & JobTracker below port

```
http://localhost:50070/
http://localhost:50030/
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a funny solution：
if you `echo $JAVA_HOME`, you may get `/usr/bin/java`
`echo export $JAVA_HOME=/usr/ >> conf/hadoop-env.sh`

Answer (score 0):

you can test it : `whereis java` 
if you can see the java 's  localtion,then you type  `env`  to watch your path.
if you had something wrong ,you need to reset you java path and hadoop path.